# How useful are UML diagram and sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I'm learning about UML diagram and sequence diagram at the moment in one of my courses for my CS degree, and I wonder that if this is something that is common to use for developers or if this is just one of many approaches to analyse the design of the system.

I'm so used to the Waterfall model and wondering if there would be any benefits for switching my mindset.

Maybe the answer is obvious, but still think it would be interesting to hear from people that are more experienced in the area.

Comment: -1 for broad, unclear not [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) question. The question would be on-topic on http://programmers.stackexchange.com site. BTW: you can find some UML tutorial materials on http://www.agilemodeling.com/essays/umlDiagrams.htm and http://www.uml-diagrams.org/uml-25-diagrams.html and welcome to Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 4):

My first advice is not to mix concepts:

**UML = modeling language**.
Useful to describe/visualize the design of a system.

**Waterfall model = design process**. 
Useful to describe in a linear-sequential manner the life cycle of a system.

This is a very short and non-deep description but ilustrates your question about the specific case of sequence diagrams, so in a real case scenario you probably will end using both like this:

-**Requirement/Analysis**: during this phase you will start creating some of the first UML Use case diagrams for your system.

-**System Design**: during this phase (or even earlier) you will start creating UML Sequence diagrams, UML Component diagrams and so on.